# Can I use my Swedish national ID card when traveling to Iceland?

Tags: paperwork, iceland, swedish-citizens

I live in Sweden and I have a national ID card. Can I use it when traveling to Iceland? In security checks, gate checks etc? Or, do I need to show my passport everytime?

Comment: Found some [info](http://m.icelandair.se/information/before-you-go/travel-documents/) from Icelandair.

Comment: What more detail are you looking for?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton references to laws etc maybe?

Comment: Inserted a link @noreputationplz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [Nordic Passport Union](https://www.norden.org/sv/treaties-and-agreements/den-nordiska-passkontrolloverenskommelsen), Nordic citizens enjoy full right of abode in each other's countries (incl. the Faroes and Greenland), are immune from deportation, and aren't even legally required to carry proof of citizenship for internal travel. This is flawed these days, stemming from a time when our countries were ethnically homogenous and it was obvious who was/wasn't a Nordic citizen.

Essentially, for all everyday practical purposes, we're not foreigners in each other's countries.

As such, we can use any official photo ID (e.g. driving licence) to travel to Iceland from another Nordic country.

However, if:

- Connecting in a non-Schengen state
- Flying Oslo ⇄ Stockholm on Ethiopian Airlines, Copenhagen ⇄ Helsinki on Sichuan Airlines, or Reykjavik ⇄ Helsinki on Juneyao Airlines

then one will clear the external Schengen border, whereby proof of citizenship (passport or national ID card) is needed.

So yes, a national ID card is sufficient under any and all circumstances.

Comment: Does this also include Swedish ID Cards issued by Skatteverket? My obviously Swedish friend was almost denied entry at the Danish-Swedish border because that was the only proof of ID he had.

Comment: @noreputationplz You mean at the former security guard operated checkpoint at Kastrup station, or on the Swedish side? For Sweden to refuse him would be plain illegal and shows the policeman was extremely improperly trained or just wanted to mess with him. But yes, there's no list of identity documents accepted within the Nordics, so it's fine on that principle (though only for internal travel)

Comment: And how about national ID cards from the rest of the European union?

Comment: @noreputationplz They're official proof of citizenship, and so officers must accept them. Even IDs from Monaco and San Marino are valid for most Schengen states (Iceland and Sweden being two exceptions)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Iceland is closely associated with the EU and all EU citizens can go there with their ID card (if they have one, of course). It's also part of the Schengen area, which means there is no systematic border checks and it's even possible you won't have to show your ID at all.

Finally, Iceland is also a member of the [Nordic Passport Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordic_Passport_Union), which means that Swedish citizens were already exempt from the passport requirement anyway, as mentioned on [the page you found](http://m.icelandair.se/information/before-you-go/travel-documents/).

Depending on airline policy and on the airport, you might still have to show an ID at some stage but your national ID card will be enough.

Comment: Have successfully travel to and from Iceland using only a national ID card.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder Your ID is valid across Europe, except for Russia, Belarus and Ukraine, as well as Georgia, French overseas territories, and on organised tours to Tunisia and Aqaba (Jordan)

Comment: @Crazydre Why is this national ID card not accepted in the French overseas territories?

Comment: @Relaxed It is, that's what I meant