# Where can you travel with a Swedish National ID Card?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, swedish-citizens, eu-id-card

I know you can visit Schengen/EES with a [Swedish National ID Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identity_card_(Sweden)), and also Croatia, Bosnia and in some cases Tunisia. Are there more places you can visit with a Swedish National ID Card?

Comment: There seems to be a [list maintained at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Swedish_citizens).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can visit the following countries using just a Swedish National ID Card:

- Nordics

  - Denmark (incl. Faroe Islands & Greenland)
  - Finland
  - [Iceland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39958/18374)
  - Norway (incl. Svalbard)
- Schengen (excl. Nordics)

  - Austria
  - Belgium
  - Czech Republic
  - Estonia
  - France (incl. overseas territories & Monaco)
  - Germany
  - Greece
  - Hungary
  - Italy (incl. San Marino & Vatican City)
  - Latvia
  - Liechtenstein
  - Lithuania
  - Luxembourg
  - Malta
  - Netherlands (European part only)
  - Poland
  - Portugal
  - Slovakia
  - Slovenia
  - Spain
  - Switzerland
- Non-Schengen EU countries:

  - Bulgaria
  - Croatia
  - Cyprus
  - Ireland
  - Romania
- Non-EU/Schengen countries in Europe (but a passport is required to fly directly from Sweden)

  - Albania
  - Andorra
  - [Bosnia and Herzegovina](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/144478/18374)
  - Gibraltar
  - Guernsey+Jersey (for those aged below 19 in an organised school group, OR the designated categories accepted for the United Kingdom)
  - Kosovo
  - [Moldova](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/77475/18374)
  - Montenegro
  - [North Cyprus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/147854/18374)
  - North Macedonia
  - Serbia
  - Transnistria (*de facto*)
  - United Kingdom for [designated categories](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visiting-the-uk-as-an-eu-eea-or-swiss-citizen), OR if entering at the Irish land border)
- Rest of the world (but a passport is required to fly directly from Sweden)

  - [Georgia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/91352/18374)
  - Montserrat (if in transit to a third country for max 14 days)
  - Morocco (1-day [excursions](https://www.frs.es/en/plan-your-trip/excursions-and-getaways/discover-morocco/excursions-1-day-to-morocco) by FRS ferry from Spain to Tangier)
  - Tunisia (package holidays)

Comment: With a valid national ID card from a EU country, you can visit all 28 EU member states, plus the four EFTA countries (Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway, and Switzerland)

Comment: The multiple listings of certain countries detracts from the readability of this answer.  The English abbreviation of the European Economic Community, furthermore, is EEC.

Comment: Not Turkey mate (however North Cyprus, practically an autonomous province of Turkey, is fine :) )

Comment: @CSM Per Swedish law you'd be correct, but in fact it's not just those

Comment: Regarding "sometimes Tunisia" to be clear it applies if you book what we call *paketresa* through a travel agent, with Almena and Detur offering trips from Sweden. However, you cannot fly directly from Sweden due to the *passlag*, as you'll be refused exit. Flying from Denmark (Almena, Detur or Sun Tours) or Finland (Detur) or any other country is fine though

Comment: This answer lacks information about the strange oddity, that it is a violation of *Swedish* law for Swedish citizens to leave from Sweden directly to a non-EEC country without a proper passport, even if the destination country accepts Swedish id cards.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Indeed, I'll add it. Also, for trivia, I'm working on an elaborate proposal of a proposition for the law to be modified to remove that restriction, which I'll send by regular mail to the Ministry of Justice (who's in charge of this law). That said, at least at Arlanda airport it's possible to trick the border police and effectively circumvent it if you know what you're doing

Comment: Svalbard is BTW not a country and there are AFAIK no direct flights from Sweden to Svalbard, but wouldn't it even be a violation of the passport law to go there with only an ID card?

Comment: @Crazydre you could also mention countries where you can transit with just an ID card, I remember you doing so in Ukraine

Comment: @JonathanReezSupportsMonica Unnecessary, as I've learnt you can transit any airport with a transit zone except in Canada, China, Mauritius and South Africa, without needing a document that would be accepted for *entry* to the transit country. I've also transited at St Petersburg, Moscow, Minsk, Istanbul and Doha (and, for that matter, used Istanbul transits as opportunities to "sneak" into Turkey)

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo AFAIK you indeed wouldn't be able to fly nonstop to Svalbard either. The Faroes and Greenland, in contrast, have open borders with Schengen (hence the latter lacks border control altogether for scheduled passenger flights), and so are unaffected.

Comment: @Crazydre that's interesting. You should create a separate Q&A about that

Comment: @JonathanReezSupportsMonica Can emphatically **not** recommend it though for those unfamiliar with the rules and who's responsible for what, as many handling agents, especially in West Europe and above all in Scandinavia, don't get this aspect. As such what I do is email the handling agent at the departure airport in advance. If they say I can fly, all good. Otherwise, I contact the airline and ask them to insert an SSR CKIN. For Belavia, Qatar Airways and Turkish Airlines I have the internal emails of the docs control specialist units, while for Pegasus and UIA, the contact centre is helpful.

Comment: @Crazydre why isn't St. Martin covered under "France (including overseas territories...)"?  And what about Sint Maarten and other Netherlands territories in the Caribbean?  Are ID cards insufficient there?  Also, I don't see any consensus that Georgia is outside Europe.  I would consider reorganizing the list to avoid making that assertion, but I'm not sure about the best way to do it.

Comment: @phoog Dutch overseas territories even refuse entry to European Dutch without a passport - European Dutch do **not** have right of abode in Dutch overseas territories (local IDs, i.e. for Caribbean Dutch, are OK for entry to the respective territory though, at least in BES). And I included St Martin due to the dual ownership, but on closer thought you're right that it's superfluous. Finally, Georgia is traditionally seen as being in Asia, so I include it in "rest of the world".